JetBrains Rider Web project: как заставить слушать 0.0.0.0 вместо 127.0.0.1?
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
мне для удобной отладки нужно запускать браузер на другой машине, а сервер (конкретно  - проект на Blazor NET Core 8.0) держать под отладкой в Jetbrains Rider.
(если быть точным - есть тестер, который знает, какие кнопки нажать, чтобы "всё сломалось", а моя задача - вдумчиво посмотреть на брейкпоинт в этот момент)
И тут обнаружилось, что сервер, который у меня запускается на URL http://localhost:5000 с другой машины - не виден.
я попробовал почитать ответы на похожий вопрос
Почистил свой launchsettings.json, сейчас там осталось
{
  "profiles": {
    "TechRiskSrv.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Потом я попробовал "хакнуть" винду, воспользовавшись командой
    netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 protocol=tcp

Это было самое загадочное - всё работало ровно до  того момента, как я в Jetbrains Rider остановил и запустил дебаг... После этого никакие пляски с бубном, сбросы, удаления и добавления заново не приводили к работоспособности.
Потом я попробовал пару "наколеночных" proxy, но для них это явно был слишком сложный номер.
Может быть, это есть где то в гиганском конфиге JetBrains Rider?
Но мои поиски не увенчались успехом.
Буду благодарен за подсказку!

portproxy для разных портов пробовали? то есть слушать один порт, а перенаправлять на другой? у вас сейчас один и тот же, это не должно работать.
